# Batch script: Convert path to linux format using wslpath

Tags: batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to convert current working directory of a .bat script into linux format by using `wsl wslpath`. To show you it works on CMD:

[image]

However, when I put it in a .bat file, and changed `%cd%` to `%~dp0`, the path is empty:
[image]

`test.bat` contains:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('wsl wslpath -a %~dp0') DO set lp=%%i
echo %lp%
```

Any idea why?

Comment: what is the chance the `wslpath` to print to the error stream? You can try with `('wsl wslpath -a %~dp0 2^>^&1')`

Comment: The result is `echo /bin/bash:`, guess it's not piped to error stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "%cd%" -- "%~dp0"
```

`%cd%` returns the path without ending backslash. So you can add a second variable that clears it.

```
set "scriptDir=%~dp0"
set "scriptDir=%scriptDir:~0,-1%"
```

UPDATE (with string substitution only - use the toLinuxPath  subroutine)

```
@echo off

call ::toLinuxPath "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp" tempF
echo %tempF%
exit /b 0

:toLinuxPath [returnVariable - the result will be stored in it; If omitted will be only echoed]
setlocal 

    set "_path=%~p1"
    set "name=%~nx1"
    set "drive=%~d1"

    set "rtrn=%~2"

    set "result=/mnt/%drive:~0,1%%_path:\=/%%name%"


endlocal & (
    if "%~2" neq "" (
        set "%rtrn%=%result%"
    ) else (
        echo %result%
    )
)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little? My final goal is to convert the path to linux format, that means from `D:\testfolder` to `/mnt/d/testfolder`, as returned by `wsl`. Do you mean I substitute my code to `FOR /F %%i IN ('wsl wslpath -a scriptDir') DO set lp=%%i` ? If yes, it's not the answer to my goal though.

Comment: @GregorIsack rather you should try with `('wsl wslpath -a %scriptDir%')` if it is not working it can be achieved with string substitution and without wsl command.

Comment: Sorry! I was meant to type `%scriptDir%` as I was typing in hurry. Any idea how to use the string substituion you mentioned? Coming from powershell, batch script syntax is very weird for me.

Comment: @GregorIsack - check my update and see if it will do the job.